# Max date of DateVector in Rcpp

Tags: r, date, max, rcpp

How to save  the maximum date within a DateVector as a variable in Rcpp?

The toy example below returns the error message:

> no viable conversion from '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Rcpp::Date
>   *, std::vector<Rcpp::Date, std::allocator<Rcpp::Date> > >' to 'NumericVector' (aka 'Vector<14>')

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Date date_toy_example(DataFrame d){

  // Get date vector from data frame
  DateVector  dte = d["date"];

  // Get max date 
  Date max_dte = std::max_element(dte.begin(), dte.end());

  // Return maximum date
  return max_dte;
}



// R code

/*** R
df <- data.frame(id=1:10, date=seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"),as.Date("2015-01-10"), by="day"))
date_toy_example(df)
*/
```

Comment: We currently have old and new vector types for dates and datetimes -- and I recommend the new ones which are available since November 2016 but will only become a default by November 2017 as we try to be gentle with API changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) returns an iterator; you need to dereference it to get the underlying value:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Date MaxDate(DataFrame d) {
    DateVector  dte = d["date"];
    Date max_dte = *std::max_element(dte.begin(), dte.end());
    //            ^^^

    return max_dte;
}

/*** R

df <- data.frame(
    id=1:10,
    date = seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"),
        as.Date("2015-01-10"),
        by="day")
)
MaxDate(df)
# [1] "2015-01-10"

max(df$date)
# [1] "2015-01-10"

*/
```

---

Alternatively, treat your input as an ordinary `NumericVector` and use `Rcpp::max`:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Date MaxDate(DataFrame d) {
    NumericVector dte = d["date"];
    return Date(Rcpp::max(dte));
}
```